# How to use SelectMany for async logic on Observable.FromEventPattern sequence?

Tags: c#, observable, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have a class that exposes the following observable sequence:

```
internal IObservable<TaskDoneEventArgs> WhenTaskDone => Observable
    .FromEventPattern<TaskDoneEventHandler, TaskDoneEventArgs>(
            handler => NiTask.Done += handler,
            handler => NiTask.Done -= handler)
    .Select(x => x.EventArgs);
```

I would like to execute some asynchronous TPL logic whenever a new item is observed from the sequence. It is my understanding that `SelectMany()` is a good way to handle the async logic. However, I am having trouble getting the syntax correct.

The following is my attempt to do so but, it will not compile:

```
_output.WhenTaskDone
    .SelectMany(async _ => await StopDelivery())
    .Subscribe(_ => Debug.WriteLine("Delivery stopped"));
```

I get the following error related to `SelectMany()`:

```
  Error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Observable.SelectMany<TSource, TOther>(IObservable<TSource>, IObservable<TOther>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. (85, 18)
```

The signature of the `StopDelivery()` function is as follows:

```
internal Task StopDelivery()
```

What am I missing and doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert a single action, based on a method that returns a `Task`, into a pipeline so that the `Task` completes before the original value is returned to the subscriber, then you need to do this kind of this:

```
.SelectMany(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => StopDelivery()), (x, y) => x)
```

Here's a complete working example:

```
void Main()
{
    WhenTaskDone
        .SelectMany(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => StopDelivery()), (x, y) => x)
        .Subscribe(_ => Debug.WriteLine("Delivery stopped"));

    NiTask.OnDone();
}

private NiTaskClass NiTask = new NiTaskClass();

internal IObservable<TaskDoneEventArgs> WhenTaskDone =>
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<TaskDoneEventHandler, TaskDoneEventArgs>(
            handler => NiTask.Done += handler,
            handler => NiTask.Done -= handler)
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs);


internal Task StopDelivery() => Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("StopDelivery"));

public delegate void TaskDoneEventHandler(object sender, TaskDoneEventArgs e);

public class TaskDoneEventArgs : EventArgs { }

public class NiTaskClass
{
    public event TaskDoneEventHandler Done;
    public void OnDone()
    {
        this.Done?.Invoke(this, new TaskDoneEventArgs());
    }
}
```

This was put together in [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net) - once you add `System.Reactive` via NuGet you can do a copy and paste and this should run fine.